# Mobile applications in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Many of us know that Delphi executables are little bit gigantic, but again it is acceptable as nowadays 1.5 mb is not a big issue in PC.

But what about mobile devices? Currently [Firemonkey](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/firemonkey) supports iOS and in the near future it is going to Android and so on. Isn't 4 mb of executable size for mobile devices is too much for a simple application?

Will Delphi team try to reduce the size of executable in the future OR is it possible to do without loosing most of the features in Firemonkey?

Comment: Just a nitpick, Delphi shells out to Free Pascal when compiling for iOS.  So those arent actually 'Delphi' executables.  At least not until they get a native ARM compiler.

Comment: The size isn't due to FreePascal, it's due to the libraries, the framework, that is what makes it big.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for crystal ball gazing of third party software offerings.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the device.

Personally I think that 4MB is not a big deal for either Android or iOS.  These devices have several GB of storage, with capacity to handle much more.  And, they have high speed data connections even over a cellular network.

I've downloaded apps (mostly games) for both platforms that are 30 MB and didn't give it a second thought.

Comment: Yes i agree with you but it is unacceptable to have 4 mb for a blank form.

Comment: That's a silly measurement, Vibeeshan.  Think about it for a minute.  Nobody actually ships empty apps, and so the difference is likely to be between a 26 meg native app and a 30 meg FMX app. The extra 4 megs represents months of your time saved by such a framework.

Answer (score 3):

It is almost 100% certain that the answer is no.

First, the commercial reality of commercial products; It is impossible for a commercial application to grow and succeed by decreasing its features.

So the answer to whether or not it is likely that smaller applications will become possible, using a framework, is NO, because the only likely change in future is that each empty app will become larger and larger as the support code which enables more and more features in each release, grows larger and larger.

If you want the absolute smallest applications, you will have to natively develop a completely separate codebase for each mobile platform that you wish to support.  You probably are aware that by doing things this way, you will get the absolute smallest app possible on each platform, but you will have to rewrite each app almost completely (you can share assets like bitmap images and sounds between platforms, but that's about it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this question yourself, by simply browsing any mobile store in... **games** category!

You'll quickly learn, that application size of 50-150 MB is nothing for both mobile device and user, if only application is worth installing and using (is usable in case of your application or have a good gameplay and marketing, in case of game). If you convince user, that installing your app is worth, he or she will install it no matter, if it takes 4 MB or 40 MB.

Please note, that the fact, that I'm answering in middle of 2015 (3,5 years after asking your question) and possible hardware expansion / growth during this period of time, has nothing to do with this. Even in time of asking this question (end of 2011) apps like Facebook or Google+ had around 50 MB of size and everyone was installing them, because they were Facebook or Google+, i.e. because people wanted to have them, not even thinking about application size or device performance.

You should also notice another thing. It is quite obvious, that people, who are installing apps from mobile stores doesn't even care for the requirements particular application has (and thus so many dumb user's devices are infected by *bad* software). If they don't even check requirements, how can we think, that they'll ever matter about app size? I can imagine (purely theoretical numbers, no source), that if only 25% of users spares 2-3 seconds to check app requirements (or think, if it can do any harm to the device) then number of users, who are actually checking application size (or care about this at all) is around 5-10%, so close to statistical error.

**If only your application is interesting to end user, he or she most likely won't take much care or won't care at all about your application size. And thus you shouldn't care much about it.**